# Given a matrix and its RREF, find missing columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are given the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&|&-6&1&2&| \\ 
2&c_2&4&3&0&c_6 \\ 
3&|&4&-1&1&|\\ 
0&|&-4&1&1&| 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{1}&0&2&0&0&0\\ 
0&\color{red}{1}&-2&0&0&2\\ 
0&0&0&\color{red}{1}&0&1 \\ 
0&0&0&0&\color{red}{1}&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $C$ is the $rref(A)$.

I am asked to find the columns $c_2, c_6$ in the origin matrix $A$, but I have no idea how to do this. The only thing I have done is colored the pivots in. How do I proceed for here?

Comment: Don't put matrices in titles. They take up a lot of room in the title and on the front page and also make it more difficult for your post to be properly searchable (for people in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse engineer the echelon form we must go back, step by step how the matrix $A$ has been reduced. Evidently we replace the values of the "missing" columns by indeterminates. We know that the first row of $C$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ but we don't know which were the coefficients, so call them  $x,y,z$ and $u$ so we have $\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z & u\end{pmatrix} A = C[1]$ giving the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
-x+2y+3z = 1 \\ xa+yc+ze+ug  = 0 \\ -6x+4y+4z-5u = 2 \\
      x+3y-z+u = 0 \\ 2x+z+u = 0 \\ xb+yd+zj+uh =0
\end{cases}
$$
If we keep away the second and last equation (which don't learn us anything) we can solve the coefficients $x, y, z$  and $u$, namely $x = -1/9, y = 1/9, z= 2/9, u = 0$. Moreover we well retain the discarded relations as $ -a/9+y/9+2e/9 = 0 $ and $-b/9+d/9+2j/9 = 0$. This completes the first step.

For the second step we note that the second row of $C$ is a combination of the last three rows with unknown coefficients $x, y, z$ . Just like in the first step this will give us five equations in which we discard two and use the others to solve for $x, y, z$ and substitute these values into the discarded equations.

After having performed step 3 and step 4 we end up with eight "discarded" equations in eight unknown. Solving this system will give you the desired solution.